# Why are there multiple gulp.dest() in this Gulp snippet?

Tags: css, gulp

I found the following Gulp snippet and I have a question about it. As you can see there is two times the `gulp.dest('app/assets/css')` part, once after autoprefixing and once at the end. I tried to remove the first one and only leave the one at the end and I didn't see any difference. So my question is is there any reason for the first gulp.dest or can it be removed? Could it be that the rename task or the cssnano task require the file to be at the destination already?

```
gulp.task('css', function () {
    return gulp.src('src/scss/style.scss')
    .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
    .pipe(sass().on('error', sass.logError))
    .pipe(autoprefixer('last 2 version'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('app/assets/css'))
    .pipe(cssnano())
    .pipe(rename({ suffix: '.min' }))
    .pipe(header(banner, { package : package }))
    .pipe(sourcemaps.write())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('app/assets/css'))
    .pipe(browserSync.reload({stream:true}));
});
```

Comment: Two versions of css being generated. one as `style.css` and another as `style.min.css`. Most likely, one for development and one for production environment.

Comment: Oh you are so right... thank you and shame on me that I didn't check it.

Comment: nah don't feel ashamed.. quite happens. Glad I could be helpful :)

Answer (score 0):

Seems that this script is also creating sourcemaps file and the also put it to the

> assets/css

directory. Actually you can remove those 2 lines:

```
.pipe(sourcemaps.write())
.pipe(gulp.dest('app/assets/css'))
```

If you don't need sourcemaps of course.

UPD:
If you will remove only first `gulp.dest()`, the second one will still writing just the sourcemaps because `gulp.dest()` command just takes passed data and writes it to the destination directory. In this cases 'passed data' is only sourcemaps. 
And in the first `gulp.dest()` the passed data is autoprefixed css.

```
.pipe(autoprefixer('last 2 version')) // autoprefixed css is ready
.pipe(gulp.dest('app/assets/css')) //css is passed to gulp.dest
........
.pipe(sourcemaps.write()) // sourcemaps are ready
.pipe(gulp.dest('app/assets/css')) // sourcemaps passed to gulp dest
```

Comment: Yeah but wouldn't the gulp.dest() after writing the Sourcemaps suffice for storing everything at the destination?

Comment: You suppose second gulp.dest() should place everything to the css directory (including minified css from upper lines)?

Comment: Thank you, but you are saying the second gulp.dest() only writes the passed data / sourcemaps. But how come then the tasks cssnano, rename and header are also triggering and saving to the destination?

Comment: because `cssnano()` and others are working with the file which was already placed to the destination directory by `gulp.dest()`. They change it but not move to another place.